# Cache a MessageProducer and/or jms Session in a Stateless EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

We experience latencies issues on our network.
I have a 1ms penalty for each connection, session and producer creation.
It's why I would like to cache my jms connection, session and MessageProducer in my stateless EJB instance variable.

I could create them in the @PostConstruct, is it safe to do that?

```java
@Stateless
public class MyEJB {
    @Resource(mappedName = Messaging.LOCAL_JNDI_CONN_FACTORY)
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Resource(mappedName = AutoRecolteIndexerConsumer.QUEUE_NAME)
    private Queue queue;

    private Connection connection;
    private Session session;
    private MessageProducer producer;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();// 1ms
        session = connection.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);// 1ms
        producer = session.createProducer(queue); //1ms
    }

    public void send(Object data) {
        ObjectMessage obj = session.createObjectMessage();
        obj.setObject(data);
        producer.send(obj);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with pre-initializing heavy weight objects like connection factories, connections, and sessions, in fact, it's good practice since we don't want to create those things each time we send a message.

But I think you're confusing stateless and stateful EJB's. You are initializing the bean's state, so it's not stateless, it's stateful. Second, since you have state, your code should assume worst case scenario and clean up resources should an error occur, like this...

```
   public void send(Object data) {
        ObjectMessage obj = session.createObjectMessage();
        obj.setObject(data);
        try{
           producer.send(obj);

        }catch( JMSException jex){
          producer.close();
          session.close();
          connection.close();
          throw new EJBException( jex);
        }
    }
```

Avoid resource leaks by cleaning up, then throw EJBException so the container destroys the EJB instance and creates a new one in its place.

Comment: Thanks, I give a try to Stateful, the application will be in preprod for the week-end, I'll accept your answer on monday depending on the results :). By the way I'm cleaning resources in @PreDestroy, I suppose it is called even on EJBException.

Comment: It works. I have to understand how pooling is working in order to check if the JMS connection pool is well suited. I use this Stateful in a MDB with a max-pool of 3. But I see many Sateful bean created (maybe 10 or 15) which are destroyed (passivated?) some hours later. I'll analyze a bit more this behaviour. Thanks.